# Functional operations with data

Tags: data, asymptotics

I have the following data (a shorter sample of the whole data) :

```
data = {{1, {{0, 1}}}, {3/2, {{0, 1}}}, {2, {{0, 1}}}, {5/2, {{0, 1}}}, {3, {{0, 1}}}, {7/2, {{2, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}}, {4, {{2, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}}, {9/2, {{3, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}}, {5, {{3, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}}}
```

A generic element in the data is given by, `{9/2, {{3, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}}`.

The 1st entry of it is some `x`. Given that `x`, there can be different `y` values namely there are only one `y=3`, one `y=2`, zero `y=1` and one `y=0`.

I want to have a "degeneracy" function `f[x,y]` which contains all the information from the data and want to study the asymptotics of that function. E.g. For fixed `y/x` and `x -> Infinity` what is the behaviour of `(f[x,y]-f[x,0])/y`?

Edit : The given `x` and `y` the function `f[x,y]` is known. From the above data, `f[9/2,2]=1` , `f[4,1]=0`, `f[3/2,0]=1`, and so on.

Comment: Then what are those 1, 1, 0, 1?

Comment: Can you give the expected output for the data that you have given?

Comment: I know the outputs from data as following. `f[9/2,2]=1` , `f[4,1]=0`, `f[3/2,0]=1`, and so on.

Comment: Maybe transforming the data into a more "regular" form (a `List` of `{x, y, z}`s) is constructive: `Flatten /@ Catenate[Thread /@ data]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not quite sure about what you want. But if your data contain the information needed to provide the output for `f[x,y]` then you may make better use of your data by converting it to an [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html):

```
assoc = AssociationThread[
    data[[All, 1]], 
    data[[All, 2]] // Map@Function[list,
       AssociationThread[
           list[[All, 1]],
           list[[All, 2]]
       ]
    ]
];
```

Now you can "lookup" the value for `f[x,y]` in your data simply by `assoc[x,y]`:

```
assoc[9/2,2]
(* 1 *)
```

Making this more comfortable:

```
f[ x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, data_Association:assoc ] := Module[
    { 
        result 
    },
    result = data[ x, y ];
    If[ MissingQ @ result,
        $Failed,
        result
    ]
]
```

Testing with your "test cases":

```
f @@@ { {9/2, 2}, {4, 1}, {3/2, 0} }
(* {1,0,1} *)
```

Hope this helps for a start.

Comment: @Physics Moron Is this helping or do you just put up a question and run? ;-)

Comment: Sorry for the delay! It was useful and I am alive! :-)